# Using react-router-dom in npm package

Tags: javascript, react-router-dom, npm-package

There is a navigation and search component in a separate npm package. These components are imported into the project in which react-router-dom is installed. I would like to use a component from react-router-dom called Link in the navigation component, as well as useLocation hooks, etc.
At the moment, I have to pass all the necessary parameters from the components to the project and route it already in the project.

The components require a BrowserRouter to work, it would be a bad way to put a BrowserRouter in each component, since they start multiplying and, moreover, do not pass the necessary data to the main BrowserRouter located in the project itself.

p.s. The components are in a separate NPM project. These components need to be inserted into another project.

Comment: please add some code so people ca help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `BrowserRouter` in your entry point `.js/.tsx` file.

If you're using `npx create-react-app .` then import `BrowserRouter` in `index.js`

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
.
. // Other Imports..
.

<React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

After that in your `App` component you need to use `<Routes>` & `<Route>`.

and All Set!

Comment: I dont use this in my NPM package

Answer (score 0):

Pass history as a prop to the Navigation Component
You can pass the history object from the react-router-dom to the Navigation component as a prop. This way, you can use the Link component and useLocation hook inside the Navigation component without needing to wrap it with another BrowserRouter. Here's an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navigation = ({ history }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  // You can use the `Link` component and `useLocation` hook here.

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        {/* Additional navigation items */}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

In your main project where you use the Navigation component, make sure you wrap your entire application (App.js) with the BrowserRouter

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navigation />
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      {/* Additional routes */}
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I will not be able to use the given component code in a separate npm package as described above, since this is a separate project and routing, namely BrowserRouter will not work.

Comment: Again, I need to import my separate NPM package into the project, this package contains the components that I want to implement into the project